# Trying to modify a.out. Segmentation Fault when writing to a.out using fwrite

Tags: c

I am trying to modify the a.out file. I am looking for a string "abc" and then replace it with "xyz". Then i have to write this into a.out
i am using fwrite to accomplish this. but it seems to give seg fault.
i am able to write to a new file with the changes made. But i am not able to write to a.out.

running on linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int  main ()
{
    static char a[100] = "abc";
    char ch, fileName[20] = "a.out";
    FILE *fp, *fpw;
    long size;
    int i;
    fp = fopen(fileName,"rb");

    if (fp == NULL)
        printf ("FILE OPEN FAILED.\n");
    else 
    {
        fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
        size = ftell(fp);
        printf("%d\n",size);
        //buffer = (char *) malloc(size+1);
        unsigned char buffer[size+1];
        fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
        fread(buffer,size,1,fp);
        int pos_search = 0;
        int pos_text = 0;
        int len_search = 3;
        int len_text = size;
        for (pos_text = 0; pos_text < len_text - len_search;++pos_text)
        {
            if(buffer[pos_text] == a[pos_search])
            {
                ++pos_search;
                if(pos_search == len_search)
                {
                    // match
                    printf("match from %d to %d\n",pos_text-len_search,pos_text);
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
               pos_text -=pos_search;
               pos_search = 0;
            }
        }

        printf("%c\n",buffer[1]);
        i = pos_text-len_search+1;
        buffer[i]   = 'x';
        buffer[i+1] = 'y';
        buffer[i+2] = 'z';
        fpw = fopen("a.out","rb+");
        fwrite(buffer,1,size-1,fpw);
        fclose(fpw);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't indent your code, it makes your life millions of times harder.

Comment: @MillieSmith: to say nothing of the lives of the people who might try to help. Thanks for cleaning OP's code up.

Comment: I can do change "abc" to "xyz" on my Linux machine by the code above. It might be better that you post the error message for debugging.

Comment: @rici you're welcome. @OP: You check whether fopen returns a valid FILE pointer for the read operation, but you don't do that for the write operation. I'm betting `fopen("a.out","rb+");` fails and returns null because "a.out" is your executable file for this program and is currently running.

Comment: This is my first post, unfortunately i thought it would auto indent. Will keep this mind. Thanks ;-)

Comment: @abhi You're welcome. For your best interests though, it's best to keep it indented even when you're working on the code. Otherwise, it's really hard for *you* to tell what's going on.

Comment: @MillieSmith yes, a.out is currently running and is there any work aorund to flush the content from buffer to a.out?

Comment: @ku' i am sorry.I am not so experienced in C programming. I donot know how to get the complete error message :(

Comment: @abhi: It's really easy: `perror`. See `man perror`. (eg. `if (fpw == NULL) perror("Couldn't open file for writing");`)

Comment: also, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893235/etxtbsy-and-how-to-override-it

Comment: `printf("%d\n",size);` uses the wrong format specifier, it should be `%ld`

Comment: @rici i have used th perror..
"TEXT FILE IS BUSY"

Comment: well..i have used unlink and then i am able to overwrite into a.out

Comment: Thank you for your time..it was really helpful :-)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close the fp handle to the file before you opened the fpw handle to the file

Comment: ... therefore `fpw` was NULL and for some reason you didn't check it.

Comment: @NealPiche Its still giving seg fault even after closing fp. And while fpw is NULL. Unable to write to a.out.

Comment: if fpw is NULL after you use fopen, then it is unable to open the file for writing, I assume you checked permissions, there could be policy like selinux and many other reasons why the file can't be written to.

Comment: Yes, but the reason is extremely unlikely to be that the file is also open for reading, since that is 100% pssibke. @millie aced this one in a comment; the problem is that the file is being executed (ETXTBSY).